# Eclipse SE is not launching

Tags: java, eclipse

I have tưo types of Eclipse IDE: SE and Indigo.

Yesterday I updated JDK 8 and Eclipse SE was still running smoothly (did not check Indigo). Before yesterday they both were working fine, but now when I click the executable file for either of them, neither one of them launches - they do not give me any types of errors, they simply do not launch. I checked the Task Manager, restarted my PC. I have heard that it is ok to have two different Eclipses, however nothing seems to be working.

What's wrong with Eclipse?

Comment: Please try running eclipse from the command line. Also, check your installation of Java. Finally, Indigo is an ancient version of eclipse. Kepler had a patch to support Java 8, but Luna is the first version with full native Java 8 support.

Comment: I tried running from cmd still nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure eclipse.ini in Eclipse home dir contains -vm param pointing to existing location

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\javaw.exe
```

Comment: What if my jre8 is in Program Files(86) ??Shall reinstall in  Program Files folder?

Comment: You can't swap from a 64-bit version of eclipse with a 64-bit version of Java, to a 32-bit version of Java. Install a 64-bit version of Java 8.